# Magento 1: is there a reason enabled = yes/no and visibility = [1,2,3,4] is not stored in catalog_product_entity

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

Magento 1: is there a reason status enabled = yes/no and visibility = [1,2,3,4] is not stored in catalog_product_entity

When trying to improve performance one could argue that table `catalog_product_entity` is at the top of the product hierarchy (also explained here https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/eav-database-structure/) and that when trying to improve performance one would want to index `status enabled = yes/no` and `visibility = [1,2,3,4]`

Is there a way to split the catalog_product_entity based on these parameters (say split catalog_product_entity based on its status being enabled or disabled)?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is using EAV data Structure. You can find this column in related tables. If you have enable flat data then search in catalog_product_flat table and you can find that column in single table. catalog_product_entity is relational table use in EAV.

Comment: But admin grid does not use flat?

Comment: Then you have to find in relational table.